# What does really mean to glue the endpoints of a closed string?

Tags: string-theory, definition, topology

I'm almost all string theory standard textbooks such as Polchinski, Barton Zwiebach's book, etc. It is stated that the Worldsheet (or parameter space) flor the closed string is such that the points $(\tau,\sigma)$ are identified via $\sigma \sim \sigma + 2\pi$. As far as I know this would mean that the elements of such a parameter space would have to be of the form $(\tau, [\sigma])$ i.e. with equivalence classes. If not, then, as the author's always do, impose  periodicity in the $\sigma$ coordinate in the function $X(\tau, \sigma)$. The problem is that $X$ should be an embedding, which is in particular bijective onto its own image (for physical reasons), which certainly a periodic map is not. Am I missing something? I'm struggling with this for a very long time and can't figure it out.

Comment: In topology, when you "glue" something, it just means that you somehow connect two points/edges/sides/whatever together to get some other kind of space where you can "cross over" the glued edge. Gluing the endpoints of a 1D string gives you a circle; gluing the sides of a paper gives you a cylinder, the sides of the screen in a PacMan game (where you exit on one end and reappear at the other, both horizontally and vertically) are "glued" to form a torus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The equivalence relation $\sigma\sim\sigma+2\pi$ is just constructing a circle for you: $\mathbb{S}^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Instead of using the equivalence class $[\sigma]$ we use a representative, say $\sigma\in[0,2\pi)$. This is always what happens with circles.
3. Periodicity is, really, a statement that the fields do not know which representative we chose to use. To them its the same if we took $\sigma\in[0,2\pi)$ or $\sigma\in[17\pi,19\pi)$.

Comment: Could 3. be rewritten as:  "I'm taking an extension of $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ to a $2\pi$-periodic map $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$" ? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Geni yes. $\ \ \ $